# Blank page is coming when using PopAsync is used for go to previous page in Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

In my app contain two pages 1. background options 2. image drawing page. These are the two pages. When I switch between these two page I fact the problem.

Scenario 1 :

When I go to background options page It will show the list of images and one button at the top of the page. If we clicked that button It will show the present application background image, If we click on that image it will go to previous page. It works fine but In my scenario 2 face the issue.

Scenario 2:

First I went to image drawing page and get back to the page using back button presented in the navigation bar and I went to the background options page, as usually it will show the list of images and button. When I press on that button It will show current background image but "When I click on that image it will show blank white page" instead of go to previous page.

I have tried a lot but con't get the reason behind this. Please suggest any idea.

Comment: The only time I've come across this issue is when I messed up the navigation stack. Can you confirm that the navigation stack has the correct pages?

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem. I managed to solve this but it was somehow complex. These are the steps (from memory):

- create a custom renderer for your pages.
- In the renderer in iOS, create a method that call the ios native pop method.
- In the iOS renderer, add a button in the toolbar on the left that will call this method.

Doing this, it will override the Xamarin forms back button. In my case, it solved my problem.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have tried that model but con't get. Please send me your sample code of what way your doing.